# angular2 can't navigating relative to parent route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I use angular2 cli .

test navigating relative met problems:

routing config:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: CheckCompanyComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path:'',
        loadChildren: 'app/components/company/check-company-home/check-company-home.module#CheckCompanyHomeModule'
      },
      {
        path:':id',
        loadChildren: 'app/components/company/check-company-detail/check-company-detail.module#CheckCompanyDetailModule'
      }
    ]
  }
```

In check-company-home component

```
goIdPage(){
    this.router.navigate(['22'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

> can navigate from "/company" to "/company/22"

In  check-company-detail component:

```
goBack(){
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

> But can't navigate form "/company/22" to "/company",

why?

Answer (score 8):

It works when I set `relativeTo: this.route.parent` and use single dot `['./']`.

```
goBack(){
    this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with only one dot:

```
goBack(){
    this.router.navigate(['./'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: in my project it works, but howsoever, you should check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40418852/6942210