# Angular 2 navigate from child to parent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can i navigate from child:

> localhost/#/pages/config/out-devices/1000

to parent

> localhost/#/pages/config/out-devices

i tried:

```
back(){
    this.router.navigate("../", {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

in the child Component but get a redirection to default site

my routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'pages',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: PagesComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'devices'},
            { path: 'devices', component: DevicesComponent },
            { path: 'groups', component: GroupsComponent },
            {
                path: 'config',
                component: ConfigComponent,
                children: [
                    // general
                    { path: 'out-devices', component: ConfigOutDevicesComponent },
                    { path: 'out-devices/:id', component: ConfigOutDeviceDetailsComponent },

                ]
            }

        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: How the the parent routes look like?

Comment: i added my routin.ts file

Comment: What component contains the `back()` method?

Comment: ConfigOutDeviceDetailsComponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate("../../out-devices", {relativeTo: this.route});
```

Comment: im redirected to localhost/#/pages/devices

Comment: Add `pathMatch: 'full'` to ` { path: '', redirectTo: 'devices'},`. All routes with empty path and no children should have `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: thx it works when i add [] to the path `this.router.navigate(["../../out-devices"], {relativeTo: this.route});`

Comment: I see, missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Does not looks like you are going to redirect from child to parents, because both `out-devices` and `out-devices/:id` are in the same children group

```
children: [
   { path: 'out-devices', component: ConfigOutDevicesComponent },
   { path: 'out-devices/:id', component: ConfigOutDeviceDetailsComponent },
]
```

You could try, this way the child component is more reuseable, since it is using redirect in more *loosely coupled* way.

```
back(){
   this.router.navigate("./", {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```